# Typescript compiler in monorepo, how to import global.d.ts

Tags: typescript

I have a npm monorepo written in javascript with jsdoc, we would like to use the typescript compiler to typecheck the project.

Monrepo:

- package A (imports common logic from package C)
- package B (imports common logic from package C)
- package C (common logic to be shared)

The problem is that I get the following error on my imports: Could not find a declaration file for module [PATH_TO_MODULE_C]

To solve this I have to generate the `.d.ts` files for the shared package (C)

If I generate them all, it works perfectly but I would like to only generate a `global.d.ts` file because I don't want 400+ new files in my package.

I suppose that I have to point out where this `global.d.ts` is somewhere but I can't find a solution. Any idea ?

I've tried many solutions which I might have not properly implemented:

- add `"types": "global.d.ts",` to the `package.json` of package C
- add the path of my `global.d.ts` to the `include` array of the `jsconfig.json` of the packages A and B
- tried to do similar thing with `typeRoots` of `jsconfig.json` files of packages A and B